# nopcommerce - multi store with product attributes

Tags: nopcommerce

We are configuring a multi-store setup. Our products have several attributes and we want to limit the values of each attribute based on the store involved. For eg. if the product is Mug, then for store A, the mug may show Logo A and Phone A to be printed on the mug but for store B, the same mug product may show Logo B and Phone B. For Store C, it could be Logo A and Phone B

How can we set this up?

If this requires customization, can you please guide me where to start as I am pretty new to nopcommerce.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to ask it here: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/f/5/general-support.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of nopCommerce 3.5 till date does not support product attributes or specification attributes to be varied by stores.

However the individual products can be limited to individual stores.
So in that case you need to create two products with the same information but different attributes and limit the products to stores.

If you really want to customize then you will have to edit the ProductBox view and I think Catalog controller to start with. For example where the product attributes and specification attributes are loaded there you might consider adding filters by stores.